# changing url endpints according current location express/axiox

Tags: node.js, express

I try to get data e from 3 differents location in my site.

1. /
2. /profile
3. /friends/profile

Express :

```
router.get("/image/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const recipe = await Recipe.findById(req.params.id);
    res.set("Content-Type", "image/png");
    res.send(recipe.image);

});
```

and in FE:

```
<img src={process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "/image/123" : `http://localhost:5000/image/123` alt="example"/>
```

its work on homepage due to img url is added to homepage
/image/:id.

but on option 2 and 3 it doesnt upload image
/profile/image/:id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create env variable like IMAGE_BASE_URL and use it in production

```
<img src={process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? process.env.IMAGE_BASE_URL+"/image/123" : `http://localhost:5000/image/123` alt="example"/>
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Do  you know more other ways for general knowledge??
and if my folder structure is with client,server,app and .env , for react should i create new .env? if so where to locate it? (currently works for me onlyhard coded )

Comment: There should be only one .env file per App. You can add more variables as per your requirement.